# Updated Xamarin to the latest version and file dependency doesn't seem to work?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I have a Xamarin application which I zipped up (externally with the MacOS archive) , sent to another user. The user did some work on it, zipped it up again and sent it back. I unzipped and everything works okay. Both of our machines when checking for stable updates show the words up to date as of October 23, 2017.

The other user (using exactly the same Mac OS hardware and version of Visual Studio for Mac OS) has files in the Solution that **show dependencies in the editor window**.

On my machine it **does not show any dependencies for any of the xaml and xaml.cs files any more** even though this appears in the the Project file:

```
<Compile Include="Views\Cards\Detail\LinkTextCell.xaml.cs">
  <DependentUpon>LinkTextCell.xaml</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

- On the other users machine the LinkTextCell.xaml.cs shows indented and under LinkText.xaml
- On my machine they both appear in the solution window at the same level.

Has anyone had the same experiences? Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or what I could look at. FYI I did try a clean all and rebuild all and that didn't make any difference.  Not sure what else to do.

Comment: I don't know... but why don't use a repository like Bitbucket?

Comment: Do you have the same versions of VS for Mac on all machines? Also do both machines have .NET Core SDK installed? There is a bug in a recent VS for Mac that affects file nesting when .NET Core SDK is not installed.

Comment: @MattWard - This may well be the problem but how can I tell if .NET Core SDK is installed and if not where can I get that from? Can you put this in an answer as it may be something that could help others also.  Thanks

Comment: The VS for Mac will list the .NET Core sdks installed in the about dialog.

Comment: I checked and .NET Core SDK is not installed on my machine but it is on the other machine.  Can you tell me where I can get this from. Also would appreciate if you could put this as an answer as maybe there are many people using Xamarin who have the same problem.

Comment: You can download .NET Core 2.0 SDK from - https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos - if that fixes the problem I can turn these comments into an answer.

Comment: yeah it fixed the problem.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio for Mac 7.2.0 currently has a bug where the file nesting does not work for .xaml and .xaml.cs files when Xamarin.Forms is used. This problem is fixed in Visual Studio for Mac 7.2.2 and later versions.

A workaround is to install the [.NET Core 2.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos).